# Slider not responding EFFICIENTLY to user's drag

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

```
<Slider x:Name="sliderBright" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Margin="132,632,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1052" Background="#FF727272" FontSize="36" BorderBrush="#FF090505" ValueChanged="SliderValue_Changed" StepFrequency="1" TickPlacement="Inline" TickFrequency="1"/>
```

Hello Guys! I'm currently working on an application which allows user to adjust the brightness of the application, its a torchlight app. Anyway my slider isnt responding to the drag , i have to tap at specific location of the bar for it to proceed to the location. When dragged, it will only move 1 value(its a bar with 100 value)

I tested in a few days back and its working but after awhile of playing around , it just becomes un-drag-able anyway whats wrong with my code, i didnt do any modification to the slider :O

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question works pretty well.  What is your event handler code?  I suggest you temporarily remove the handler and see if it works.